# Why do I get this error message?

Tags: javascript

This line of code:

```
document.getElementById("you").innerHTML="hello world";
```

Gives me this error message in the javascript console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property of 'innerHTML' of null.
```

Can someone explain why? Because it's clearly not null..

*EDIT* Here is the rest of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"
</script>-->
<!--<script src="myjavascript2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">

<script>
document.getElementById("you").innerHTML="hello world";
</script>
</head>
<body>


<select id="select">
<option>Rock</option>
<option>Paper</option>
<option>Scissors</option>
</select>



<p id="opponent">You chose:</p>


<p id="you"></p>

<span id="displayresult"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's clearly `null`. At least when that line of code runs.

Comment: Post the rest of your code please.

Comment: document.getElementById("you") is null. Are you sure that the element's id is "you"?

Comment: Any chance of accepting an answer?

Comment: None of the answered were correct tho, figured out the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* null. Your script is running before the element exists. Either do it onload:

```
onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("you").innerHTML="hello world";
}
```

Or right after the element:

```
<div></div>
<script></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Cannot set property of 'innerHTML' of null.`**

It is indicating that the element is not present

it may also be the case you are checking even before loading the element.

Try checking on load

```
document.onload = function () {
document.getElementById("you").innerHTML="hello world";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is no such element with id `you`. Please recheck for the ID.